# ActiveRecord query error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have an ActiveRecord query in a controller:

```
t="example_name"
i = Item.where(:name => t)
```

This doesn't cause an error, but it doesn't seem to be returning the right thing. In the rails console, it returns a normal Item and I can access all the attributes, but looking at some print statements I put in, I can see that

```
i.class = Item::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

Whereas when I make the call as

```
i = Item.find(4)
```

for debugging purposes,

```
i.class = Item
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, especially since the where() query works in the rails console

Comment: ActiveRecord's `where` method will always return a ActiveRecord::Relation object. It is kind of an array, filled with all the results (or none) matching the conditions given to the `where`. So when you call `Item.where(name: 'hey')` it actually returns all Item records having their name equal to "hey". In your case, do `Item.where(name: t).first` to get the first instance of Item matching your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you use a `#where` query in Rails, it returns as an ActiveRecord::Relation. This is beneficial to you, because Rails is avoiding the performance overhead and just saying, "I found these results according to the query you gave me."

[Here's a link to the Rails docs.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database)

Comment: You can use an Enumerable like `#each` to perform a given method on each result, or any other method in the Enumerable Module in Ruby. If you know you're only going to have a single instance as the result of any given `#where` call, you could simply append `.first` to the end of your query. It really depends on your application needs.

Comment: thanks! I deleted my comment because the other person had already answered